# Microsoft JScript runtime error: 'DeleteRowFromCart' is undefined

Tags: javascript, asp.net

I have been lately facing with this "function undefined error" and its a little bit frustrating.

I have a web application where i am trying to build my *java-script* page dynamically using a `StringBuilder` class in the code-behind. In my code-behind I'm associating an `OnClick` event for an anchor tag.

The click event never seems to fire .

I always get the error saying:

> Unhandled exception at line 794, column 1 in script block 0x800a1391 -
>   Microsoft JScript runtime error: 'DeleteRowFromCart' is undefined

**Javascript code :**

Script includes

```
<link href="Styles/jquery.mobile-1.2.0.min.css" rel="stylesheet" 
    type="text/css" />
<script src="Scripts/jquery.min.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
<script src="Scripts/jquery.mobile-1.2.0.min.js" type="text/javascript" >
</script>

<script type="text/javascript">
    function DeleteRowFromCart(tableID) {
        // Function Logic             
    }
</script>
```

**Code behind :** : Build the page dynamically

```
StringBuilder cartString = new StringBuilder(string.Empty);
cartString.Append(@"<tr><td></td><td align='right'>
    <a data-role='button' data-mini='true' data-icon='delete' data-theme='a' 
    onclick='DeleteRowFromCart("+ product.TableId+");'>Delete</a></td></tr>");
cartString.Append("</table></li>");
CartPanel.Controls.Add(new LiteralControl(cartString.ToString()));
```

The CartPanel here is an ASP Panel

```
<asp:Panel runat="server" ID="CartPanel" />
```

I don't know what could be possibly wrong here .
Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: run your application, then from your browser see the page source, is DeleteRowFromCart is exists ? Also can you post the generated html for Delete button  ?

Comment: The function 'DeleteRowFromCart' doesn't exist in my source. And one more weird thing is when i view source i don't see any html for my controls which i am building dynamically. Rather it is showing the HTML content of my Start up page in the solution. Is that how it is supposed to be ?

Answer (score 0):

single quote could be a problem try replacing the following -

```
onclick='DeleteRowFromCart("+ product.TableId+");' to onclick=DeleteRowFromCart('"+ product.TableId+'");
```

Update - add javascript before function.

```
string TableID="Table01";

 StringBuilder cartString = new StringBuilder(string.Empty);
 cartString.Append(@"<tr><td></td><td align='right'>
 <a data-role='button' data-mini='true' data-icon='delete' data-theme='a'
 onclick=javascript:DeleteRowFromCart('" + TableID + "');>Delete</a></td></tr>");
 cartString.Append("</table></li>");
 CartPanel.Controls.Add(new LiteralControl(cartString.ToString()));
```

Comment: Thanks for the reply . I did try to change the quotes but it gives an error because the way you have specified the quote seems wrong to me . Shouldn't the OnClick be enclosed inside single quotes ?

Comment: As an update i did try to change the statement to 

    onclick='DeleteRowFromCart();'

It gives the same error for a simple function too .

Comment: No sadly even alert doesn't work . I am starting to get a little paranoid now .

This works.

`<script type="text/javascript">
 alert('success')
</script>`

but if i add a simple function in there which does the same thing then it doesn't work

Comment: After careful deletion of tags and trial and error finally i found the solution . Now i don't get function undefined, but rather i get   "0x800a1391 - Microsoft JScript runtime error: 'gucci1' is undefined"   Where gucci1 is the parameter i take in the `'DeleteRowFromCart(TableId)'` function .  By the way the error Function undefined was solved by removing an attribute called `data-role="page"`

Comment: can you share the source (view source) of the page ?

Comment: The code is working fine now. Im able to get rid of the error .